# Volatile variable read behavior

Tags: java, concurrency, lazy-loading, volatile, vavr

I have encountered the following code when reading Vavr's `Lazy` source code:

```java
private transient volatile Supplier<? extends T> supplier;
private T value; // will behave as a volatile in reality, because a supplier volatile read will update all fields (see https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile)
```

```java
public T get() {
    return (supplier == null) ? value : computeValue();
}

private synchronized T computeValue() {
    final Supplier<? extends T> s = supplier;
    if (s != null) {
        value = s.get();
        supplier = null;
    }
    return value;
}
```

This is a famous pattern called "Double-checked locking", but it looks broken for me. Suppose we embed this code in a multithreaded environment. If the `get()` method is called by the first thread and the supplier construct a new object, (for me) there is a possibility for another thread to see the semi-constructed object due to reordering of the following code:

```java
private synchronized T computeValue() {
    final Supplier<? extends T> s = supplier;
    if (s != null) {
        // value = s.get(); suppose supplier = () -> new AnyClass(x, y , z)
        temp = calloc(sizeof(SomeClass));
        temp.<init>(x, y, z);
        value = temp; //this can be reordered with line above
        supplier = null;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Unfortunately, there is a comment next to the `value` field:

```
private transient volatile Supplier<? extends T> supplier;
private T value; // will behave as a volatile in reality, because a supplier volatile read will update all fields (see https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile)
```

As far as I know, a volatile read will "refresh" values of variables that are read after a volatile read. In other words - it drains the cache's invalidation queue (if we talk about MESI coherence protocol). Additionally, it prevents loads/reads that happen after the volatile read to be reordered before it. Still, it doesn't give any guarantee that instructions in object creation (calling supplier `get()` method) will not be reordered.

My question is - why this code is considered thread-safe?

Obviously, I haven't found anything interesting in the source placed in the comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don’t talk about caches when it comes to Java’s memory model. What matters, are formal *happens-before* relationships.

Note that `computeValue()` is declared `synchronized`, so for threads executing the method, reorderings within the method are irrelevant, as they can only enter the method when any thread which executed the method before, has exited the method and there is a *happens-before* relationship between the method exit of the previous threads and the next thread entering the method.

The really interesting method is

```java
public T get() {
    return (supplier == null) ? value : computeValue();
}
```

which does not use `synchronized` but relies on the `volatile` read of `supplier`. This is obviously assuming that the initial state of `supplier` is non-`null`, e.g. assigned in the constructor and the surrounding code ensured that the `get` method can not get executed before this assignment happened.

Then, when `supplier` is read as `null`, it can only be the result of the write, the first thread executing `computeValue()` has done, which establishes a *happens-before* relationship between the writes that thread made before assigning `null` to `supplier` and the reads this thread makes after reading `null` from `supplier`. So it will perceive a completely initialized state of the object referenced by `value`.

So you are right that the things happening in the value’s constructor can be reordered with the assignment of the `value` reference, but they can not be reordered with the subsequent write to `supplier`, which the `get` method is relying on.